# Setting up CLASS PATH for Tomcat on 64bit Windows

Tags: java, tomcat, batch-file, servlets

I have a problem with setting up the `CLASSPATH` for Tomcat, following [this Tutorial on Servlets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm).

It says that I need to set it inside `autoexec.bat`, however, I am using Windows 7 64bit, and as I googled, this file does not exist here, so I cannot edit it.

**QUESTION:**

How can I set the `CLASSPATH` without editing `autoexec.bat` to be able to run `Java Servlets` ?

I have tried running the example `HelloWorld.java` without setting the `CLASSPATH` but it returns errors, since it cannot find the necessary `JARs`.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: what IDE are you using? is that eclipse?

Comment: No, I use Android Studio. But I created the HelloWorld.java example inside SublimeText with simple Copy/Paste and saving it C:\ServletDevel  as it's mentioned in Tutorial.

Comment: There should be no need to fiddle with CLASSPATH for running Tomcat - Tomcats startup scripts will do that for you. You may set the CLASSPATH from Windows system control panel, but again: a proper IDE will do that automagically for you! This tutorial seems somewhat outdated...

Comment: Thought so. Soo stupid of me...I should just create this project inside Android Studio.  Eh..sorry for this question..

Comment: `Android studio` is not the most suitable IDE for servlets better use eclipse for JEE.`AUTOEXEC.BAT` is an ancient configuration script and is not available from Vista and above you can use `SETX` instead but this is needed in case you start the tomcat by yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys! Will use Eclipse to try this out!

Comment: If you are an android studio user, you'll have a much better time with IntelliJ. There's a free community edition.

Comment: @npocmaka I am trying now to use it with Eclipse, but it won't allow me to import `javax.servlets` libs. Do I need to download those JARs manually and import them inside the project?

Answer (score 0):

It's an environment variable. You set it like any other.
Try using 'set' at the command-line, or 'setx' to male it permanent. See http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html.

You can also set it in tomcat's 'setenv.bat' startup file.